# Clear form fields on firefox

Tags: firefox, forms

Firefox stubbornly persists in filling out a form for me. I've already tried clearing the cookies and form history.

Any ideas as to how to keep the form fields blank?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Security. Try checking saved stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open Firefox/Options/Privacy there should be an option (check box) that allows you to "Remember Search and Form History" if you uncheck that box firefox won't retain and form data.

You could also use inbuilt privacy cleaner or something like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to remove this data periodically.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to delete individual entries by using the up/down keys to highlight them and hitting shift+delete.

See "Delete Selected Autocomplete Entry": http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/keyboard+shortcuts